# Sum in a table created by a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-tables

**EDIT**

now I have this html:

```
<table id="consumo">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Semana</th>
                    <th colspan="7">Consumo de alimento diario</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Total Semana</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Acumulado</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Consumo Diario</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Consumo por pollo semana</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Consumo Acumulado</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Lunes</td>
                    <td>Martes</td>
                    <td>Miércoles</td>
                    <td>Jueves</td>
                    <td>Viernes</td>
                    <td>Sábado</td>
                    <td>Domingo</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><input class="con_sem_1" name="con_lun[]" type="text"
                        onkeypress="numeric(event)" size="6" value=""></td>
                    <td><input class="con_sem_1" name="con_mar[]" type="text"
                        onkeypress="numeric(event)" size="6" value=""></td>
                    <td><input class="con_sem_1" name="con_mie[]" type="text"
                        onkeypress="numeric(event)" size="6" value=""></td>
                    <td><input class="con_sem_1" name="con_jue[]" type="text"
                        onkeypress="numeric(event)" size="6" value=""></td>
                    <td><input class="con_sem_1" name="con_vie[]" type="text"
                        onkeypress="numeric(event)" size="6" value=""></td>
                    <td><input class="con_sem_1" name="con_sab[]" type="text"
                        onkeypress="numeric(event)" size="6"></td>
                    <td><input class="con_sem_1" name="con_dom[]" type="text"
                        onkeypress="numeric(event)" size="6" value=""></td>
                    <td><input id="tot_sem_1" disabled="disabled" size="7"></td>
                    <td><input id="acum_sem_1" disabled="disabled" size="7"></td>
                    <td><input id="con_diario_sem_1" disabled="disabled" size="7"></td>
                    <td><input id="con_x_pollo_sem_1" disabled="disabled" size="7"></td>
                    <td><input id="con_acum_sem_1" disabled="disabled" size="7"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

and this javascript code:

```
function calcular() {
    var total = 0;

    $(".con_sem_1").each(function(){
        if (!isNaN(this.value)) {
            total += parseInt(this.value);
        }
    });

    $("#tot_sem_1").val(total);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#consumo").on("keyup", ".con_sem_1", calcular());
});
```

and it still does not work.

Comment: It's confusing what you're trying to get the sum of? The text fields have no values in them. Also why can't you put the table into the html page?

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward I'm trying to get the sum of the fields with the `name="con_*"` and I had the table in html but traversing the html was really hard.

Comment: But you still don't have values to add together. You're essentially saying null + null = null. You must have something like value="4" or something like that first. Also it's really easy to traverse through the html but first please confirm you meant to have values in the inputs.

Comment: yes, i mean to have values in the inputs, it just creates them empty

Answer (score 0):

We can simplify this js code down very easily. So long as you put the table into the html and have values for them you could use something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>

</title>
<script src="http://www.andy-howard.com/js/libs/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

total = [];

$(".fieldToAdd").each(function ()                                         
    {
    currentNumber = parseInt($(this).val());
    total.push(currentNumber);
    });
    total = eval(total.join('+'));
    alert (total);
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td><input class="fieldToAdd" type="text" value="1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input class="fieldToAdd" type="text" value="2" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input class="fieldToAdd" type="text" value="3" /></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```